# Rails - multiple association unknown attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, associations

I'm making an API in Rails, and has a Model called Match which has 2 association to the User model defined as

```
belongs_to :user_a, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_a'
belongs_to :user_b, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_b'
```

In User model:

```
has_many :matches
```

In my Match controller spec, I'm doing the following:

```
before(:each) do
    user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    api_authorization_header user.auth_token
    @match_attribs = FactoryGirl.attributes_for :match
    post :create, { match: @match_attribs }
end
```

and the tests fails with "unknown attribute: user_id"

If I make the change to post:

```
post :create, { user_a: user.id, user_b: user.id, match: @match_attribs }
```

then its still giving me unknown attribute.

Edit: scheme for matches:

```
create_table "matches", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_a"
    t.integer  "user_b"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "matches", ["user_a"], name: "index_matches_on_user_a"
add_index "matches", ["user_b"], name: "index_matches_on_user_b"
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Post your schema.rb files that shows your columns.

Comment: edited my post @Daiku

Comment: i think i found the problem, in my user model I should set the foreign key to user_a. but how i have 2 user association in my Match model, what should i write then in my User model?

Comment: Well, don't you need to create two users, and link them together with a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails and SQL convention dictate that foreign keys should end in `_id`, e.g. `user_a_id`, `user_b_id`. Since Rails is built around "convention over configuration," convention will make your code simpler. If you change the field names, the code becomes:

**match.rb**

```
belongs_to :user_a, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :user_b, class_name: "User"
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :matches_a, class_name: 'Match', foreign_key: 'user_a_id'
has_many :matches_b, class_name: 'Match', foreign_key: 'user_b_id'

def matches
  Match.where("user_a_id = :id OR user_b_id = :id", id: id)
end
```

Using a method is the only way to make this kind of relation. This way will return a relation that you can further query, while simply concatenating the other two relations (`matches_a + matches_b`) will return an array.

Comment: seems to be working, but when im creating the matches on the test cases, i should write like this?

`post :create, { user_a: user.id, user_b: user2.id, match: @match_attribs }`

Comment: The foreign keys should be included in `@match_attribs`, so it would be `{ match: @match_attribs.merge(user_a_id: user.id, user_b_id: user2.id) }`

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to make it work with your schema is to put in user model:

```
has_many :matches_as_a, foreign_key: 'user_a'
has_many :matches_as_b, foreign_key: 'user_b'

def matches
  matches_as_a + matches_as_b
end
```

If there is another way, I'd be glad to know it and refactor some of my apps (not including join models, of course) ;)